# Does a column still called primary key if it is currently didn't contain duplicate data BUT it could contain duplicate data?

Tags: database

If a table only have 1 column that currently does not contain duplicate data , BUT it could contain duplicate data in the future , is it still called primary key ?

Example

| Name | Flight Destination | Flight date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Abrams | USA | 20 October 2021 |
| Jack | England | 20 October 2021 |
| Lily | USA | 1 December 2021 |

The only column that doesn't have duplicate data is the name column . Because it didn't contain duplicate data , therefore it is CURRENTLY uniquely identifies each row record in the table (because there is no duplicate data) .

But there is a chance in the future that the column could contain duplicate data (because people might have the same name) , so is it still called primary key or no ?

Edit : clarification

Comment: It is one if you configure it to be one

Comment: It it can potentially contain duplicates, it's not a primary key (not even a unique key)

Comment: @Nico Haase No no no , it isnt for practical purpose , just theoretical , so i dont get it wrong in my future exam

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name so the answer is no because it could contain duplicate data even though it is currently didnt contain duplicate data?

Comment: If this is theoretical: why do you care? Either the data can be used for non-duplicate data, or it can not. This all depends on your use case.

Comment: @NicoHaase One of my assignment literally asked me to find the primary key from a table , so it has nothing to do with use case

Comment: Usually, you would not use a column as a primary key if you can already see that it might hold duplicated values in the future

Comment: Yes i know , every developer would scream if someone uses name column as primary key . But i have already said this is just theoretical purpose (to answer my assignment) , not for use case.

Comment: Then what's your question? What kind of answer are you waiting for?

Answer (score 1):

A primary key should only be applied to a column if *the field* is a unique identifier for each *individual* record.

For example: an employee ID could be a primary key, but something that may seem unique but isn't **necessarily** unique such as birthday or name, isn't. Even if no two records have the same birthday or name currently, doesn't mean they can't.

Each field in a primary key field must be unique to the record it's associated with.

Edit: clarification

Comment: Yes, the table you posted has no suitable primary key fields. If there was a field with passsport number for example, that could be a primary key.

Comment: The name field currently didn't contain duplicate data , so as long as nothing says it couldnt contain duplicate data , it isnt called unique identifier ? therefore , it isnt primary key ? please, this is to answer the question in my assignment

Comment: The name field doesn't contain duplicate data *currently*, but that doesn't mean it can't. If you marked name as a primary key and tried to add a record with the name 'Lily', you'd be in trouble.. A primary key field is a field that can be used to uniquely identify any record in your database (commonly an ID number, order ID etc).. Mark as answer if you understand,

Comment: *If you marked name as a primary key and tried to add a record with the name 'Lily', you'd be in trouble* . This is just theoretically not practically . Yes i know that practically i would get *trouble* if i use name as primary key and tries to add duplicate data , but since this is theoretical purpose i dont really care.

Comment: If your question is *can you* mark a field with no duplicate data with a primary key, the answer is yes. If the question is *should you* mark a field that can possibly have duplicate data but currently has no duplicate data with a primary key, the answer is no for the reason I've explained.

Comment: let me clarify , because it can be marked as primary key , therefore **the name column is currently a primary key?**

Comment: No. While it is possible to mark name as a primary key, it's not a unique identifier for records as **more than one record can have the same value for Name**, a primary key must have a **unique value for every single record in the database**, both currently and regardless of the records added to the database.